# Vector2 does not exist in the namespace 'SharpDX'

Tags: c#, directx, sharpdx

Im trying to use sharpdx to render graphics but am running into trouble from the off. I have imported sharpdx, d3dcompiler 3d11 and dxgi yet even the most simple of drawing operations will not work as my error list tells me that the type or namespace 'Vector2' does not exist in the namespace 'SharpDX'

I've had a look at the solution for sharpdx on github and it does indeed have a class called vector2 in a namespace called sharpdx so I am confused as to why i cannot call it

Comment: Show your source file that is causing the error...

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using SharpDX 3.0+, you need to add a reference to the [`SharpDX.Mathematics`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpDX.Mathematics/) assembly which was previously integrated into the core assembly but is now separated.

Answer (score 0):

1- You need to reference the library `SharpDX` to your project which can be downloaded from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpDX/).

Also, if you're using Visual Studio, here's a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio) on how to add its package to your project.

2- If typing `Vector2 variable = XY;`  fixes nothing, then try typing `SharpDX.Vector2 variable = XY;`